# PHP Logtail solution

Tags: php

I would utilize the unix logtail to grab the end of some logfiles periodically but I realized it shouldn't be that hard to implement this in php itself.

The php logtail examples what I find online are rather "php tail" implementations.

What the unix logtail does is every time you read from a logfile it saves the offset somewhere, then when you run it next time you will only get the new lines from that log.

This is exactly what I need if there is no new data I don't want to return any lines.

Could any skilled php coder modify this for me to do the same?

```
<?php

class LogRead
{
    private $filename = '';

    function __construct($filename) 
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    public function tail($lines = 10) 
    {
        $data = '';
        $fp = fopen($this->filename, "r");
        $block = 4096;
        $max = filesize($this->filename);

        for($len = 0; $len < $max; $len += $block) 
        {
            $seekSize = ($max - $len > $block) ? $block : $max - $len;
            fseek($fp, ($len + $seekSize) * -1, SEEK_END);
            $data = fread($fp, $seekSize) . $data;

            if(substr_count($data, "\n") >= $lines + 1) 
            {
                /* Make sure that the last line ends with a '\n' */
                if(substr($data, strlen($data)-1, 1) !== "\n") {
                    $data .= "\n";
                }

                preg_match("!(.*?\n){". $lines ."}$!", $data, $match);
                fclose($fp);
                return $match[0];
            }
        }
        fclose($fp);
        return $data; 
    }
}
?>
```

Thx!

Comment: How big are these logfile going to get? A read into memory solution would be simple if the files wont get huge

Comment: Hello. The logs are not larger than 50megs and I could rotate them out but the whole point of using offset is that you don't start reading from the beginning (at least for the second time:)